# Is the 'Unit step function' indeed a function?

Tags: functions, step-function

I have read in an article that '*We do not define $u(t)$ at $t=0$. At $t=0$ we think of it as in transition between $0$ and $1$*'.

The domain of the Unit step function is the real numbers, but if $u(t)$ isn't defined at $t=0$ then it isn't function, right?

But then, why do we call this Unit step function a "function"? Or is the above quote from the article wrong?

Comment: It is a function [defined on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $\mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$

Comment: There are more than a few conventions, including the one cited by the commenter above, but you can define it on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Even the wikipedia page cited defines it at $0$ too for some of examples. Just follow the convention relevant to you.

Comment: It is similar to the way that its derivative, the Dirac delta function, is not a function. There is a related question about the connection.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734716/this-is-function)?